# How to keep a button centered on an image on all viewpoints in CSS (or bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a button centered on my hero image but with my current way I would have to use many media querys to keep it centered on all viewpoints.

```
<style>

 .hero-container{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
 }

  .hero-btn-div{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 42%;
   display: inline-block;
  }

 .hero-btn{
  background-color: transparent;
  font: var(--main-sans-serif);
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
 }

</style>

<div class="hero-container">
  <img src="images/dream%20of%20winter%20cut.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="1920px" alt="Artwork">

  <div class="hero-btn-div"><a href="#"><button class="hero-btn">Button</button></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will update `left:50%` and add this `transform:translateX(-50%;)`

```
 <style>
  .hero-container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .hero-btn-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .hero-btn {
    background-color: transparent;
    font: var(--main-sans-serif);
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
  }
</style>

<div class="hero-container">
  <img src="images/dream%20of%20winter%20cut.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="1920px" alt="Artwork">

  <div class="hero-btn-div"><a href="#"><button class="hero-btn">Button</button></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: an outdated technique that is not necessary sicne you have stuff like `flexbox` which also causes far elss potencial issues.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add picture as a CSS `background-image` property inside container div, then center button via flexbox.

Another solution is to absolute position image inside container div, and then center button via flexbox -> example:

```css
.hero-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero-container .bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.hero-btn {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  font: var(--main-sans-serif);
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container">
  <div class="bg-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img-fluid" width="100%" alt="Artwork">
  </div>

  <div class="hero-btn-div">
    <a href="#">
      <button class="hero-btn">Button</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: Don't ever use fixed sizes (1920px) if you want to build a responsive web page.

Comment: please do not add a fiddle to show that your answer works, add a [repro] instead. Please also read [why an image of your code is not acceptable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) which also applies to any other external sources as fiddles and codepens.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what you are trying to accomplish, since we cannot see the image or don't know what the .img-fluid class is supposed to do. But, since your main issue appears to be the centering of content, I would advise looking into the "display: flex" property (more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)). Moreover, [this](http://howtocenterincss.com/) could be a handy tool for you.

I would try if the following solution works for you to keep the button centered:

```css
.hero-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-btn-div{
  position: absolute;
}

.hero-btn{
  background-color: transparent;
  font: var(--main-sans-serif);
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container">
  <img src="images/dream%20of%20winter%20cut.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="1920px" alt="Artwork">

  <div class="hero-btn-div">
    <a href="#">
      <button class="hero-btn">Button</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sry for not including the img-fluid class. It is a bootstrap class that adjusts the image to the breakpoint size

Answer (score 0):

You can stretch the wrapper for the button to the full size of the container and center the button with **display: flex**. Dont forget about **pointer-events**.

```css
 .hero-container {
    position: relative;
 }

 .hero-btn-div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

 .hero-btn {
    background-color: transparent;
    font: var(--main-sans-serif);
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    pointer-events: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but I would use Bootstrap's flexbox classes...

```
<div class="hero-container">
    <img src="..." class="img-fluid" width="1920px" alt="Artwork">
    <div class="hero-btn-div d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><a href="#"><button class="hero-btn">Button</button></a></div>
</div>
```

With a full size absolute container...

```
 .hero-btn-div {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
 }
```

[Responsive demo](https://codeply.com/p/5qMHKgGfLV)